# This code is no working and error is shown at compilation?

Tags: geolocation, street-address, google-geocoder, dot42

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Os;
using Android.Widget;
using Dot42;
using Dot42.Manifest;
using Android.Location;


[assembly:UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)]
[assembly:UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.INTERNET)]
[assembly:UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)]

[assembly: Application("simplegps")]

namespace simplegps
{
    [Activity]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        private LocationManager service;
        private bool enable;
        private string provider;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance) 
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
            SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);


            var txtprovider= FindViewById <TextView>(R.Ids.txtprovider);
            var gpsstatus= FindViewById <TextView>(R.Ids.gpsstatus);
            var txtcity = FindViewById<TextView>(R.Ids.txtcity);
            var txtlat = FindViewById<TextView>(R.Ids.txtlat);
            var txtlon = FindViewById<TextView>(R.Ids.txtlon);

            service=(LocationManager)GetSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            enable=service.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


            if(enable)
            {
                gpsstatus.Text="Gps enabled";
            }

            else
            {
                gpsstatus.Text="Gps not enabled";
                return;
            }

            var criteria = new Criteria{Accuracy = Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE};
            provider = service.GetBestProvider(criteria,false);
            var location = service.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location !=null)
            {
                txtprovider.Text=provider;
                var latitude = location.Latitude;
                var longitude = location.Longitude;

                txtlat.Text=latitude.ToString();
                txtlon.Text=longitude.ToString();
            }

            else
            {
                txtprovider.Text="no location";
                return;
            }

            if(Geocoder.IsPresent())
            {
                Android.Location.Geocoder geo;
                Android.Location.Address adds;
                  adds=geo.GetFromLocation(location.GetLatitude(),location.GetLongitude(),1);

            }
        }
   }
}
```

error message:
It shows error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Util.IList' to 'Android.Location.Address'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)"

Comment: You are trying to cast a a type of List to a type of Address. Not sure where though. It is possible that its somewhere in the dot42 code. You should report it as a bug and try to use the Native JAVA way instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line that fails:

```
adds = geo.GetFromLocation(location.GetLatitude(), location.GetLongitude(), 1)
```

`geo.GetFromLocation` returns `Java.Util.IList<Address>`. `adds` is of type `Address`. Hence the compile error.

Use the index operator to access one of the Addresses.

[image]

EDIT

Also, you should initialize `geo` before using it:

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

Finally, GetFromLocation may return null or an empty list, so check for both.